# Read all slack messages of all users

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I want to receive all the events/messages coming and going from all the users to all the channels or other users in a workspace.
There is a way to get messages of a particular user(sending/receiving) by creating an app and using event subscription(https://api.slack.com/apps/A01SP2TL45B/event-subscriptions?).
Is there anything like this available to get all users' events?

Answer (score 0):

There is `discovery.user.conversations`

> This method lists IDs for all conversations (channels and DMs, including public, private, org-wide, and shared) a user is in